# Use truncatingRemainder() method in Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, methods

I am trying to create a 3D cube animation in objective-c.Here is a piece of code that I would like to use my code. Does someone knows how to convert these method to objective-c ? I didn't find anything in Apple documentation.

```
let hasCompletedPaging = (xOffset / scrollView.frame.width).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Apple's documentation for **truncatingRemainder** the C-style version of this function looks like this:

```
CGFloat TruncatingReminder(CGFloat x, CGFloat dividingBy) {
  return x - dividingBy * floor(x / dividingBy);
}
```

P.S. I know that my answer is quite late but may be it will be useful for some one.

Answer (score 1):

`truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)` gives just the fractional part of the result. So comparing `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)` to `0` is the same as checking if the result is a whole number.

One simple conversion could be:

```
BOOL hasCompletedPaging = (xOffset / scrollView.frame.width) == round(xOffset / scrollView.frame.width);
```

But that's not ideal due to the imprecision of floating point numbers.

A better check might be:

```
BOOL hasCompletedPaging = fabs(xOffset / scrollView.frame.width - round(xOffset / scrollView.frame.width)) < 0.000001;
```

But the easiest solution is to use `fmod`. When the result is zero, it means the first number is an integer multiple of the second:

```
BOOL hasCompletedPaging = fmod(xOffset, scrollView.frame.width) < 0.000001;
```

Comment: Or `fmod(xOffset, scrollView.frame.width)`

Comment: @MartinR How to convert var rightAnimationPercentComplete = hasCompletedPaging ? 0 : 1 - (xOffset / scrollView.frame.width).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)

Comment: @kroko `double rightAnimationPercentComplete = hasCompletedPaging ? 0.0 : (1.0 - fmod(xOffset, scrollView.frame.width));`. But (in either language) why would you want 0% if it's complete?